# Downloading files from the most recent directory with wget or curl

Tags: curl, ftp, directory, wget

I have the following, particular situation: FTP server at ftp://ftp.sanger.ac.uk/pub/gencode/Gencode_mouse/ contains directories with various versions of mouse genome sequences (M1-M13). I would like to be able to tell wget or curl to enter the most recent (i.e. newest) directory, without having to manually check which one that is, so that I can download the newest versions of files that I need for my work using a bash script/oneliner, without having to check the latest version number beforehand.

So, something like:

```
wget ftp://ftp.sanger.ac.uk/pub/gencode/Gencode_mouse/release_M**(newest)**/*.primary_assembly.genome.fa.gz
```

I don't know how to pass the **(newest)** part to wget or curl.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but here,

```
#! /bin/bash
##
# Get latest version
LATEST=$(curl -s4 ftp://ftp.sanger.ac.uk/pub/gencode/Gencode_mouse/ | grep -Eo 'release_M[0-9]+' | sort -nrt M -k2,2 | head -n 1)

# Download from latest folder but only if match pattern
wget -r -A '*.primary_assembly.genome.fa.gz' "ftp://ftp.sanger.ac.uk/pub/gencode/Gencode_mouse/$LATEST/"
```